# Sort the array inside the meteor collection

Tags: meteor

I have such collection structure:

```js
{
    _id: "JPsqqGJBgpwix5AqM",
    images: [
        {
            id: 123456,
            created: Thu Nov 14 2013 22:58:11 GMT+0200 (EET),
            height: 115,
            width: 350,
            url: "http://www.test.com/alckxm.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 123456,
            created: Thu Jan 24 2013 01:46:55 GMT+0200 (EET),
            height: 115,
            width: 350,
            url: "http://www.test.com/awerrkxm.jpg"
        }
    ],
    username: "John"
},
...
```

What I need is to return all images from this collection, sorted by the date.

I've tried all of the following:

```js
return Users.findOne({username: "John"}, {created: 1})
return Users.findOne({username: "John"}, {"images.created": 1})
return Users.findOne({username: "John"}, {sort: {created: 1}})
return Users.findOne({username: "John"}, {sort: {"images.created": 1}})
```

but nothing of this worked.

Is it even possible to do that now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort is used only to sort whole documents. You'd need to do a `findOne` and then sort the images array separately. For example:

```
var images = Users.findOne({username: "John"}).images;
return _.sortBy(images, function(image){ return image.created; });
```